# Public work is the same as studying Torah?

Tags: torah-study

I am bothered by this quote:

> Yerushalmi [5:1]: Rabbi Yirmiyah said: One who is occupied with the needs of the public is equivalent to one who is occupied with the study of Torah. [Tosafot on Ber. 31a]

What does it mean?  That if one takes care of the congregation's synagogue building  and grounds, or serves on the Board, or heads the Membership Committee, or visits all the sick, he does not have to study Torah?

(On the other hand, *V'talmud Torah k'neged kullam* [Peah 1:1, Shabbat 127a, Kiddushin 40a, Tanhuma Yitro 14] does imply that if you do *kullam* you don't need to study.)

Comment: Specifically, See commentaries in Rambam tefilah 6:8

Comment: If there weren't people to take care of the public needs nobody would be studying Torah.

Comment: See Tur’s interpretation 93 (with Prishah)

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel -- what tractate in the Yerushalmi?

Comment: Berachot 36a or so I believe

Comment: To the Rambam, I think, yes. To others, I think, no.

Comment: Dear @Shmuel, would you be able to explain your comment above, “To the Rambam, I think, yes. To others, I think, no.”, it sounds like an interesting perspective, but the language is like a closed book [Isa.29:11] to me.

Comment: @Dr.Shmuel Coming from a Reform perspective, my rabbi once told me that the Rambam put emphasis on good deeds as much as Torah study. Reading the Talmud, some rabbis think good works is very important and some rabbis in our history would study Torah or Talmud for hours, implying that Torah study is key. Personally, I think Torah study and good public works go hand-in-hand.

Answer (score 1):

Your quotation excludes its context and thus creates a potentially misleading premise.

This law is codified in Shulchan Aruch (93:4):

> העוסק בצ"צ כעוסק בתורה דמי פירוש לענין לעמוד מתוכו להתפלל שגם זו שמחה היא לו שעוסק בצרכי צבור וי"מ דהיינו לענין דאינו צריך לפסוק להתפלל:
>   One who is busy with communal needs is like someone who is busy with studying Torah, similar to what we discussed about the matter of standing from it to pray -- that here, too, this is a joy for the person who is busy with communal needs. And there are those who are lenient/stringent, that is to say, for this matter that one does not need to stop [serving communal needs] in order to pray (Sefaria).

In general, I tend to agree with the sources you have graciously included, in that indeed Torah study is the best.